# Building Ros Melodic from source fails at vcs import src < melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I decided to build ROS Melodic from source instead and deleted all ROS Melodic packages and installation binaries.

I've been following these steps: wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source

Unfortunately it fails at `vcs import src < melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall` with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vcs", line 7, in <module>
    from vcstool.commands.vcs import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .branch import BranchCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/branch.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/command.py", line 6, in <module>
    from vcstool.executor import execute_jobs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstool/executor.py", line 31
    file=stdout)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What can I do to fix this problem? I found nothing while searching for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411112/building-ros-melodic-from-source-fails-at-vcs-import-src-%3C-melodic-desktop-full.rosinstall/) by [xdzye](https://answers.ros.org/users/125007/xdzye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2023-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: you're using Python 2, which the main distribution(s) of `vcstool` no longer support.

You'll either have to use Python 3 to run `vcstool`, or switch to the [0.2.x branch](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool/commits/0.2.x).

I'd suggest the former.

Note this is mentioned [in the readme](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool/tree/daf389377310f7f31b2171f51a79af82c31bf3e2#python-27---34-support) of `vcstool`:

> ### Python 2.7 / <= 3.4 support
>
> The latest version supporting Python 2.7 and Python <= 3.4 is 0.2.x from the [0.2.x branch](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool/tree/0.2.x).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xdzye](https://answers.ros.org/users/125007/xdzye/) on 2023-01-06**:
Ok, thank you very much! I thought melodic is better to run with Python 2.7, or should i rebuild with Python3?

I saw this thread: https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/ and also your answer that suggests one can use basic functionality when building with python3, but I need opencv etc. to use rtabmap. Should I just stick to 2.7?

I also found a gist that suggests another installation path for ros melodic with python3: https://gist.github.com/MBaranPeker/3005ed281cf03922d641ba98bf8088eb
I dont really understand the sed commands in the gist so I cant judge if this would build all packages with Python3.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-01-08**:
It's perfectly possible to use Python 3 for `vcstool` while using Python 2 for Melodic.

There is no need to build Melodic from source, nor for Python 3.

**Comment by [xdzye](https://answers.ros.org/users/125007/xdzye/) on 2023-01-18**:
Thank you, I got it working.